# Manage multiple clients / domains Magento 2 marketplace

Tags: magento, magento2, marketplace

I hope someone can help me with below in Magento 2. How can we manage multiple clients / domains with the new marketplace?

For example we are developing www.domainA.com and www.domainB.com, do we have to make a seperate account Marketplace account: https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/applications/customer/create ?

Because these are two different clients? And we don’t want that they can see it’s purchases into the backend of Magento (Component Manager).
And for these clients in their marketplace account we can generate a private and public key and insert that into ./composer/auth.json within FTP of their Magento installation ?

My only problem on that is, we are purchasing the software for our clients. So for each client we have to make a different Marketplace account and fill in our company details for purchasing items. The marketplace account is connected to an emailadres as username.

We don’t want to fill in the customers email address, because then this clients gets all the emails from Magento. How can we manage this?

Best regards, Tim